# Multilingual spell check

Tags: languages, spell-check

I have found a few similar questions but no answers yet.

I use the Microsoft SwiftKey keyboard so I can type in both English and Dutch simultaneously (without having to switch between them). This works great but the system spell checker still put red lines under all my words. I have set the spell checker to 'use system languages' but it only uses the first one in the list. If I select manually, I can only use one language. Is there a way to get multilingual spell check?

Answer (score 2):

My experience has been that this may not be possible, but probably depends on which phone you're using. My current and past two phones flat out would not allow me to set SwiftKey as the global spell-checker. (I can *autocorrect* with it, but with two languages plus dialect plus slang in the "learned" dictionary... this is not especially useful.)

I would check that your default spell-checker is actually, or even can be, set to SwiftKey. On my current Samsung with android 11, the spell-checker setting is completely integrated and only available under "Samsung keyboard settings" (meaning I can only use the native Samsung keyboard if I want to enable it), while on the older Huaweis (android 6 & 9), it was called "Spelling correction," but the only selection possible was Gboard.

([Someone elsewhere on SO suggested this was a change in android 5,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30977600/7448796) and looking at the releases, the SpellCheckerService class pops up in API 14/android 4, so it may be that the global function didn't even exist until then.)

Edited to reiterate: N.B. that I'm specifically responding to the question as to "spell-checker" and **not** "autocorrect" (as it sounds like @metshein is referencing below), which (somewhat confusingly) are actually two different settings. The OP mentioned "red lines" below words, which is a spell-checking function separate from autocorrect, which can be enabled or not within SwiftKey.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Samsung Galaxy A7 and I have 3 languages in my keyboard and spell checker and it works just fine. Maybe like 1% of the time it might correct my Estonian word to a Swedish one but that's because the words can be quite similar.
And I'm also using the Swiftkey keyboard so I guess it really might depend on the phone but it shouldn't..doesn't make much sense xd